# Apache httpClient.execute() NoSuchMethodError - project builds ok, but this happens at runtime?

Tags: android, eclipse

A few days ago I moved my Eclipse project from one folder to another and set up the dependencies again.

The project now builds perfectly and the app runs until it gets to this piece of code:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Where I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
```

In the `libs` folder I have these jars:

```
httpclient-4.3.5.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.5.jar
```

And here is how my Order and export looks like:

[image]

And my libraries tab

[image]

EDIT: Another thing I tried was downloading the lastest httpcore, httpclient and httpmime and replacing the jars in the libs folder

And I also added them as `Add External Jars` in Libraries tab of `Configure Build path`

Comment: Since you are moving just go little further and Choose Android Studio please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by downgrading to versions 4.1 or httpcore, httpclient and httpmime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about how you could resolve the error, especially since you seem to be using Eclipse, but as an alternative, you could try [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library. It has very good performance and you could easily modify your codebase with this change.

Comment: I cannot afford to rewrite the whole networking of this app. It is a legacy project and I just had to add a small feature to it, and it wont work anymore. It used to build and work just fine before I moved it to another folder...

Comment: could you try it on Android Studio to see if you are having same problem? Eclipse has a reputation for annoying programmers with these kind of things.

Comment: I need at least 4 hours to migrate it to android studio, it has lots of modules, dependencies, changed libraries, jars...

Comment: can you try adding three httpXXX jars to project's build path and at the order and export tab move these there jars to top and try to run again

Comment: @guleryuz did that, no result